# (SOLVED) Body moving in viscous fluid - Laplace

Tags: laplace-transform

### **Problem**

The velocity for a body moving in a viscous fluid has the following diff. equation:

$$a v'(t) + b v(t) = c(t)$$
$$v(0) = 0$$

Where $a$ is the mass of the body, $b$ is the frictional force from the fluid, and $c(t)$ is a pulsive force applied to the body which is, at first, stationery in the water.
The force $c(t)$ can be approximated with any arbitrary impulse function, but it has to meet the following conditions:

1. $$c(t) \ne 0 \text{, for a very short time interval around $t = 0$}$$
2. $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} c(t) \text{ } dt = d$$

The body is finally at rest for $t < 0$.

$$\text{a, b, d > 0, and they are shall be treated as known parameters}$$

**Task**:
Find $v(t)$, for $t$ $\geq$ 0

### **My attempt**

I first formulated a solution for $v(t)$ using Laplace transform for the diff. equation.

$$\mathscr{L}(a v'(t) + b v(t)) = \mathscr{L}(c(t))
\implies V(s) = \frac{C(s)}{as+b}$$

And then I tried to find an arbitrary impulse function that would meet the conditions.

We know that:  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} c(t) \text{ } dt = d$$

And we can also know that if we integrate the standard Dirac-pulse distribution/function $\mathcal{ D}(t)$
we get

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{D}(t) \text{ } dt = 1$$

due to $d$ just being a real constant we get

$$d\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{D}(t) \text{ } dt = d$$
$$\iff$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\mathcal{D}(t) \text{ } dt = d$$

And also

$$\mathcal{D}(t) = {\infty} \text{ for t = 0}$$

$$\mathcal{D}(t) = {0} \text{ for } t\neq 0$$
$$\implies$$
$$c(t) = d\mathcal{D}(t)$$
$$\implies$$
$$C(s) = d$$

So now we can solve for $V(s)$
$$V(s) = \frac{d}{as+b} = \frac{d}{a}\frac{1}{s+\frac{b}{a}}$$
Which gives us our inverse
$$v(t) = \frac{d}{a}e^{-\frac{b}{a}t}$$

### **The issue**

Now as from the description of the problem, we know that the function $v(t)$ is at rest for $t < 0$, which I interpret as $$v(t) = 0 \text{ for } t < 0$$

But in the function $v(t)$ we have no restriction for the domain of the function.
So I'm thinking v(t) should've had a Heaviside step function multiplied to it.
But also, the function depends fully on the parameters, {a,b,d}, for different values. Yes, we do get an exponential function, so it will always be positive, and
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}  v(t) = 0$$
But I don't like the fact that with a force applied to the body, the function would slowly descend towards 0.

Sorry for the messy post, I had to learn latex to rewrite all the mathematical bits by coding it in latex.

Summary of the issue is that we don't have any restrictions in our $v(t)$, so the function is defined for $t < 0$, I would like to see a Heaviside step function in our $v(t)$ but we have none, and I don't know right now how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really have anyone to verify my solution with, but after working a bit more with the problem I realized that my solution must be the right one. Because when I read the problem again, I could just interpret $v(t)$ as two cases.
$$v(t) = \frac{d}{a}e^{-\frac{b}{a}t} \text{ for } t \geq 0$$
$$v(t) = 0 \text{ for } t < 0$$

Another addition would be that we define the Laplace transform of a function for the interval $t = [0,\infty)$

Also as we do have an engineering/real-life applicational problem, it's not reasonable to even think of the function for negative intervals for $t$. Because we want to evaluate the transient response.

I feel so stupid, I am now 99.99% sure that I have the right solution.
But if anyone here would like to add anything or maybe prove me wrong, please do.